# Screen doesnt work with Ryzen 5600G on mainboard hdmi connector

Tags: hardware-failure, amd-ryzen

I have a new pc without a dedicated graphics card and a ryzen 5600g. When i plug the hdmi cable into the mainboard at the back of the case the screen stays black. Ive just bought a used radeon hd 5770 to update the bios in case the current bios doesnt support the cpu, but the screens (i tried another one) also dont work with the graphics card. i plugged the graphics card into both fitting pcie-slots on the mainboard but it didnt work out. I have no idea what i can do now.

the setup is

- msi mpg b550 gaming plus
- amd ryzen 5600g
- 650w power supply
- 64gb 3600 ram from kingston

and a radeon hd 5770 for testing purposes

Comment: You plugged the monitor into the GPU or the motherboard when you installed the temporary GPU? Are you sure the CPU is properly installed? Is there any sign the board is actually successful trying to POST?

Comment: at first i plugged it into the mainboard when there was no gpu. when i installed the gpu i plugged the monitor into the gpu and out of desperation into the mainboard again.
i dont know, the mainboard is illuminated and there is no blinking or beeping like i experienced booting errors in the past.
its hard to tell without a screen.

Comment: If you try to boot it up with no RAM plugged in, do you get any error beep codes?

Comment: yes i do. i also noticed that the mainboard isnt just illuminated. its a debug led that tells me the ram isnt working properly. ive sent it back and will try the new ram. thanks for the help.